# How to separate these strings using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have collection of string like `'36*' , '95' , '103*', '1001*' , '2301'`.

I want to separate these into two parts the numerical part into integer and the asterisks part. 
eg: take 36 from first, 95 from second, 103 from third and so on. I add them all. If asterisk is found then multiply the number with some factor.

The asterisk is always at the end.

Comment: [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: explain more what do you really want to do?

Comment: I want to separate these into two parts the numerical part into integer and the asterisks part. 
eg: take 36 from first, 95 from second, 103 from third and so on. I add them all. If asterisk is found then multiply the number with some factor.

Comment: You mean something like this `'36' * factor , '95' , '103' * factor, '1001' * factor , '2301'`?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract out the parts you need using a regex.

```js
var values = ['36*', '95', '103*', '1001*', '2301'];

var parts = values.map(function(x) {
  var match = /(\d+)(\/|\*|\+|\-)?/.exec(x);

  return {
    numericPart: match[1],
    operator: match[2]
  };
});
```

You can then access the numeric or operator part for each element in your original array. i.e. `parts[2].numericPart == 95`

The regex `(\d+)(\/|\*|\+|\-)?` can be broken down as follows;

```
(\d+) - matches 1 or more digits and stores them in capture group 1
(\/|\*|\+|\-)? - matches a /*+- and stores it in capture group 2, this matches 0 or 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['36*' , '95' , '103*', '1001*' , '2301'];
var t = [];
var f = [];
arr.forEach(function(e){if(e.indexOf("*") > 0){ t.push(e) } else { f.push(e) } } );

console.log(t); //asterisk values
#=> ["36*", "103*", "1001*"]
console.log(f); // other value
#=> ["95", "2301"]
```

if you want to multiple the each element of the array of asterisk elements  to a factor like 10

```
arr.forEach(function(e){if(e.indexOf("*") > 0){ t.push(parseInt(e)* 10) } else { f.push(parseInt(e)) } } );

 console.log(t); //asterisk values
#=> [360, 1030, 10010]
console.log(f); // other value
#=> [95, 2301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will take an input and will return the number & special symbol(*).

```
function _seperateNum(value){
    var returnObj={}; // This object will contain number * special character(if)
     var replaceChar=""; 
     if(value.indexOf("*") !=-1){ // check if input has *
        replaceChar = value.replace(/[*]/g, ''); // replace it
       returnObj.num = parseInt(replaceChar); // convert to number
        returnObj.char = "*";
      }
      else{ // if no special charcater
       returnObj.num = parseInt(value);
     }
     return returnObj;
    }
    var a =_seperateNum("36*");
    console.log(a.num);
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3146nxLx/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var 
        arr = ['36*' , '95' , '103*', '1001*' , '2301'],
        sum = 0;
    for (var i in arr) {
        var item = arr[i];
        sum += parseInt(item.indexOf('*') != -1 ? item.replace('*', '') : item);
    }
    alert(sum);
```